# how to unit test sorting on a table from sapui5

Tags: unit-testing, sapui5, qunit

I have this table (m.Table) in my ui5 application that I'm sorting using the following example.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.42.7/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableViewSettingsDialog/preview

I have a set of unit test (QUnit) where I test this functionality but I keep getting an error saying that "Object doesn't support method sort".

This is a snippet of my code

```
var oBinding = controls.searchResultsTable.getBinding("items");
var aSorter = [];
var sPath = "columnName";

aSorter.push(new Sorter(sPath, false));//sort in descending order 
oBinding.sort(aSorter);
```

This code above takes care of the sorting when the application runs and everything works fine.

Here is a snippet of my testing

```
QUnit.test("valid search input", function(assert){
   ....
   //my attempt at testing this
   var getBinding = sinon.stub().returns(new sap.ui.model.Binding(), 
                         function(){}); 
 }

 var oBinding = {getBinding: getBinding};
  ....
```

The error points to the line where I do aBinding.sort(aSorter);
Looking at the api, the sap.ui.model.Binding doesn't have any "sort()" functions. So I'm not sure how the sorting even works, let alone test it. Could someone give me some guidance here?

Answer (score 0):

because `sort` is done on `sap.ui.model.ListBinding` as you are doing a binding on table items. [Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.ListBinding)

Also there are different other Bindings which extends `sap.ui.model.Binding` like `sap.ui.model.PropertyBinding`(binding on single UI control), `sap.ui.model.TreeBinding`(binding on Tree control) and so on.